# Error calculating RegionDifference of two disk sectors

Tags: regions, mesh

I am trying to implement an exercise that should be straightforward. I have two sectors of disks (in blue and orange below) with an overlap. I am trying to calculate their Region Difference, but it doesn't work! There is no subtraction! Is this a bug related to meshing and the curved geometry?

Code:

```
\[Phi]f = Pi/3;
Rf = 1.0;
sectorOrigin = {0, 0};
smallSector = Disk[sectorOrigin, Rf, {-\[Phi]f/2, \[Phi]f/2}];
minRadiusSector = Disk[sectorOrigin, Rf/2, {-\[Phi]f/2, \[Phi]f/2}];

Graphics[{{Orange, smallSector}, {Blue, minRadiusSector}}]
RegionDifference[smallSector, minRadiusSector];
Region[%]
```

Please advise.

[image]

Comment: Work in 13.0.0 in Windows 10. Maybe version issue.

Comment: Works in v12.2 Win7-x64: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd68Q.png).

Comment: It works also in version 11.3 for Linux

Comment: You mean, all of you are seeing a sector of an annulus? Could you please share your output? I have Mathematica 12.0. I don't see it.

Comment: I did some tests and I believe the region is being calculated properly, but `Region[]` is not displaying it correctly. Any guesses as to why?

Comment: You can test another function. `reg = RegionDifference[smallSector, minRadiusSector];
GraphicsGrid[{{Region[reg], 
   RegionPlot[reg, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic]}, {BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg], 
   DiscretizeRegion[reg]}}]`

Comment: No luck. I get the same thing back again. Interestingly, if I change the angular extent of the large sector to `smallSector = Disk[sectorOrigin, Rf, {-\[Phi]f, \[Phi]f}];`, it works!